# Iron router data not found not working properly

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

I have the following code in my router file.

```
Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {except: ['home', 'tests']})
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound')
Router.onBeforeAction('loading')

Router.configure ->
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
  notFoundTemplate: '404'


#define routes
Router.map ->

  @route 'chat',
    path: '/chat/:room_name'
    waitOn: ->
      [Meteor.subscribe('rooms'),
      Meteor.subscribe('users'),
      Meteor.subscribe('bookmarks', @params.room_name),
      Meteor.subscribe('notifications'),
      Meteor.subscribe('usersNoteCount'),
      Meteor.subscribe('system_messages', @params.room_name)]
    data: ->
      Rooms.findOne({room_name: @params.room_name})
```

And whenever I run into the case where a specific room doesn't exist, the page still tries to render the chat page when the data is `null` or `undefined`.

I am not sure how to go about fixing this as everything I have read tells me this is the exact way to handle a not found page.

**EDIT**

With the above code edit, I am still having an issue where I am either loading forever, or I get rid of the two subscriptions that require a parameter, I am seeing a blank page on load. What am I doing wrong here?

The loading forever issue I feel I need to fix on the publish side, but I am still not entirely sure how to fix it.

Comment: But this isn't a not found page - the path will be perfectly valid even if the room name isn't in the database, it just won't have any associated data.  The issue is that you need to handle the case where the data context is empty, either on the page itself or using the `dataNotFound` method referred to by David Weldon.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the [docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md), you need to add `Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound')`. Give that a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I just updated the code to reflect the issues I am still having.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it doesn't work properly at the moment.

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/745